# Downward preserving the ccc-ness of a poset between generic extensions.

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I am self studying the proof of consistency of MA. At some point it seems that we need something like this:

> Let $M$ be a countable transitive model for ZFC. Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be forcing posets, with $P_1$ completely-embeddable into $P_2$. Suppose that $P_2$ is ccc. Let $G$ be $P_2$-generic over $M$. Suppose that $(X, {\leq}) \in M[G]$ and $(X, \leq) \in M[G \upharpoonright P_1]$. If $M[G] \models$ "$(X,\leq)$ is a ccc poset", then also $M[G \upharpoonright P_1] \models$ "$(X,\leq)$ is a ccc poset".

I already know that $G \upharpoonright P_1$ is $P_1$-generic over $M$ and $M[G \upharpoonright P_1] \subseteq M[G]$.

If $P_2$ were countably-closed, then this would be trivial, because it would preserve $\omega$-sequences. But this is not the case, so maybe we have an antichain $A \in M[G \upharpoonright P_1]$ which is of course countable in $M[G]$, but it might happen that the injection $f \colon A \to \omega$ is not in $M[G \upharpoonright P_1]$.

How can I handle this? Thank you.

**Edit: Proof attempt.**

Suppose to the contrary that $M[G \upharpoonright P_1] \models g \colon \omega_1 \to A$ is injective. Then $M[G] \models g \colon \omega_1^{M[G \upharpoonright P_1]} \to A$ is injective. But $\omega_1^{M[G]} = \omega_1^{M[G \upharpoonright P_1]}$ because $P_2$ is ccc and hence preserves $\omega_1$, and this is impossible.

Is that correct?

Comment: Do you have examples of countably closed ccc forcings which are not trivial?

Comment: I don't think so...unless I didn't realize it :)

Comment: Also, being ccc is not the same as being countable. So you want $g$ to enumerate some antichain, and not just be injective.

Comment: @AsafKaragila what do you mean? $A$ is an antichain! The proof attempt uses the same notation as above...and of course there I mean that $A$ is an antichain _in $(X,\leq)$_. Maybe I should be more precise...

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. I misread your post.

Comment: No problem :) but so the proof looks fine to you?

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me. In general, begin $ccc$ is a $\Pi_{1}$ statement in the paremeter $\omega_1$. So, as long as $\omega_1$ is absolute between two transitive structures $M \subseteq N$, it is preserved upwards. This is essentially what you've proved.